# Working with multiple threads and while updating the UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

### Background Info:

I'm creating a batch encoder for my project. It's something like this: (I just need to add a *Cancel* button inside each item and replace the placeholders)

[image: Batch Encoder]

For each item added, a thread/task should process a given information (image) and saved on disk as an encoded image.

I'm used to work with `delegate` and `delegateObject.BeginInvoke(...)`, but I only updated the UI with `static` calls inside the `delegate` method.

### The Problem:

I did that with `WinForms` and not exactly with a dynamic list of items. 
Also I'm not familiar with the cancellation of threads/tasks from the UI.

### The Question:

I need a little push to head to the best way of approaching this problem.

How to manage multiple parallel operations and update the UI?

Comment: This is really broad, and you haven't really asked a question yet. Could you try narrowing it down? Note that with MVVM, *most* changes are correctly marshaled with no extra effort!

Comment: Assuming you have a list of “tasks” where each task has a worker thread and a property tracking the progress, you can just update that task’s progress property from within the thread (alternatively on the UI thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` and the view that is bound to the properties will update automatically.

Comment: I already have an answer. A list of tasks did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code. It will run the encoding process side-by-side and will update the UI if the `InternalUpdate` method is called with the correct ID of the `Task`.

### Working Code:

```
int a = 0;
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var task = new Task(() =>
{
    Encode(listFrames, a);
},
_cancellationToken.Token);

//Unique ID.
a = task.Id;

//Adds the item to the list.
var encoderItem = new EncoderListViewItem
{
    Image = (UIElement)Resources["Image"],
    Text = "Starting",
    Percentage = 0,
    Id = a
};

EncodingListBox.Items.Add(encoderItem);

_taskList.Add(task);
_taskList.Last().Start();
```

To update each item:

```
private void InternalUpdate(int id, double percentagem, string status)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var item = EncodingListBox.Items.Cast<EncoderListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Percentage = percentagem;
            item.Text = status;
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using cancellation tokens. Something along the lines of:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _cts.Token;
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
           // Your encoding process
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
       // Handle cancellation
    }
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_cts != null)
        _cts.Cancel();
}
```